# Recent activity is not recorded or lost

Tags: search, file-search, synapse

A couple of days ago I started to experience issues with *search/activity* log on my Arch Linux system to be precise what I mean I'm using search tools like *Synapse* and basic one from *Cairo Dock* both of them stopped showing results either I search or try to see my *recent activity* none of these tools show anything except *Cairo Dock tool* shows what has changed in *Pictures* folder and that is weird that it affects for example *Documents* folder but *Pictures* activity shows up normal but *Synapse* search tool shows nothing at all. I've been using *Synapse* for about 4 years already and this thing never happened and I'm wondering what could be the sudden cause for this issue? I didn't do any changes or modifications to my system just a routine updates via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but I'm guessing there's some *Synapse* search tool issue with the newer linux kernels I've tried to purge it completely and reinstall but no success but installing alternative search tool [*Albert*](https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/using/) works even better for me. For those who used to *Synapse* alike search tools might want to try an alternative app launcher *Albert* works flawless. To install *Albert* on Arch Linux use the command below:

```
yaourt -S albert
```

To install *Albert* on other distros [click here](https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/installing/)